# Dwarf Fortress for Windows Mobile

Tags: dwarf-fortress, windows-mobile

Is there any possibility of playing Dwarf Fortress on a Windows Mobile phone?  I keep hearing great things about this game, but it seems that the only chances I have of getting any gaming in these days is via my phone.

Comment: @C. Ross is right on the money.  I would add, though, that even on pretty hefty desktop hardware DF tends to max out processor time.  I imagine if you tried to run it on a phone you would get a bad framerate for five minutes before your phone either ran out of battery or overheated.  DF is not NetHack!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your only hope currently is to run DF on a Linux machine and create a terminal to it.  You will also need to set the output type to curses with the following changes in the config file.

```
[SOUND:NO]
...
[PRINT_MODE:TEXT]
```

I would also suggest making the following change in the init file for ease of play (the intro doesn't work well in curses mode).

```
[INTRO:NO]
```

However with the small screen and small keyboard DF will probably still not be at its best.

Comment: darn, i was hoping for something other than terminal'ing into a server...ty for the info!